# intercambiar el src de 2 iframes al darle click

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

Quiero que cuando se haga click en el frameDos ese se pase al frameMain
Lo pienso hacer que cuando se haga un click en el framDos este intermcambie las etiquetas del src pero no me sale :c

Lo pienso hacer que cuando se haga un click en el framDos este intermcambie las etiquetas del src pero no me sale :c
Porfavor y gracias de antemano

```
    const frameMain = document.querySelector('.frameMain');
    const frameDos = document.querySelector('.frameDos');

    //intermcabio el src del iframe de la izquierda con el de la derecha al darle click al iframe de la derecha
    frameDos.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const srcMain = frameMain.querySelector('iframe').src;
        const srcDos = frameDos.querySelector('iframe').src;
        frameMain.querySelector('iframe').src
        = srcDos;
        frameDos.querySelector('iframe').src
        = srcMain;
    });
```

'''

```
</head>
<style>
section{
    padding: 10%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
</style>

<body>
<section>
 <div class="frameMain"><iframe width="610" height="315" 
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uiiss0hP8xM?start=246" title="YouTube video player" 
 frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="frameDos"><iframe width="410" height="250" 
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TqTEJ-Jd6Ug" title="YouTube video player" 
frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; 
 gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
   </section>


  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al hacer clic, estás haciéndolo sobre el iframe (ya ves que el vídeo se inicia cuando ocurre), no sobre la capa `frameDos`. El prolema está en que los iframe no están pensandos para usar el evento onclick.

Una opción es superponer una capa transparente a modo de botón sobre el iframe de `frameDos` para que, al hacer clic sobre ella, se cargue el vídeo en el iframe de `frameMain`.

Así se haría con un `button`, que requiere algunas líneas más de CSS que una capa o un enlace, pero tiene mayor sentido a nivel de código:

```js
const frameMain     = document.querySelector('.frameMain').querySelector('iframe');
const frameDos      = document.querySelector('.frameDos').querySelector('iframe');
const frameDosBoton = document.querySelector('.frameDos').querySelector('button');

frameDosBoton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const srcMain = frameMain.src;
  const srcDos  = frameDos.src;
  
  // El '?autoplay=1' es opcional (hace que se autoreproduzca el iframe principal)
  frameMain.src = srcDos + '?autoplay=1';
  frameDos.src  = srcMain;
});
```

```css
section {
    padding: 10%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.frameDos {
  position: relative;
}

.frameDos iframe {
  z-index: 1; /* Opcional: Si el iframe se incluye antes del button en el código HTML, no hace falta z-index */
  position: relative;
}

.frameDos button {
  z-index: 2; /* Opcional: Si el iframe se incluye antes del button en el código HTML, no hace falta z-index */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Propiedades específicas para button, cambiarían para un div, un enlace, etc. */
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;  
  background-image: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="frameMain">
    <iframe width="610" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uiiss0hP8xM?start=246" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="frameDos">
    <iframe width="410" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TqTEJ-Jd6Ug" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <button title="Reproducir vídeo en la ventana principal">Reproducir vídeo en la ventana principal</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: hermano, muchisimas gracias, realmente entendiste mi duda. gracias hermano me sirvio a la perfecion